# Readability of very long complex type parameter with lambda expression?

Tags: c#

The following function uses a very long and complex type `Long_complex_type` and it's hard to read. I tried to add parameter to the function but it doesn't work and `var` doesn't support lambda expression. What's the best way to make the code more readable besides `using-alias-directive`? (I don't want to create many type aliases, ideally the type can be inferred)

```
private void MyFunction()
{
    Func<Long_complex_type> dowork = () => _service.GetSomething(.....);
    Action<Long_complex_type> then = (Long_complex_type l) => { _view.DoSomething(l); };
    ....... 
}
```

Comment: You mean using `var`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: Can you give one or two examples of "Long_complex_type"?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel `var` can't be used with delegate types

Comment: @NWard `var` can *absolutely* be used with delegate types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create a factory method which will allow you to use type inference:

```
public static Func<T> CreateDelegate<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    return function;
}
public static Action<T> CreateDelegate<T>(Action<T> action)
{
    return action;
}
```

You can now write:

```
var dowork = CreateDelegate(() => _service.GetSomething(.....));
var then = CreateDelegate((Long_complex_type l) => { _view.DoSomething(l); });
```

Comment: Almost perfect. However, still have to write the type of `l`, which may be mandatory.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 You could infer it if you had an object of that type, or an object that used it as a part of it's type (through generics).  You can't infer the type of something you know nothing about, obviously.

Comment: Theoretically the type of `l` can be inferred from `_view.DoSomething(l)`.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 No, it cannot.